# Ошибка при выводе из модели в вид: "undefined variable..."

Tags: php, kohana

Cоздал модель **application**:

```
defined('SYSPATH') or die('No direct script access.');

class Model_Application extends Model
{
    protected $_tableApplications = 'applications';

    /**
     * Get all articles
     * @return array
     */

    public function get_all()
    {

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM ". $this->_tableApplications;

        return DB::query(Database::SELECT, $sql)
               ->execute();
    }

}
```

А в контроллере **main** передаю в вид:

```
<?php defined('SYSPATH') or die('No direct script access.');

class Controller_Main extends Controller_Base {

    public function action_index()
    {

        $apps = array();

        $apps = Model::factory('Application')->get_all();

        $this->template->content = $apps;

    }

}
```

В БД естественно есть таблица **applications** с какими-то данными, в самом виде, допустим вывожу ид-шники:

```
foreach ($apps as $app){ echo $app['id']; }
```

Ошибка **undefined variable apps**. Что тут не так пошло, кто может подсказать?

**upd** 1. Попробовал за**bind**'ить, но ошибка та же:

```
defined('SYSPATH') or die('No direct script access.');

class Controller_Main extends Controller_Base {

    public function action_index()
    {

        $apps = array();

        $content = View::factory('main')
                ->bind('apps', $apps);

        $app = new Model_Application();
        $apps = $app->get_all();

        $this->template->content = $content;

    }

}
```

Comment: Судя по первой вашей попытке, можно предположить, что цикл обработки $apps находится в шаблоне (``$template``). Это так?

Comment: по сути у меня $template это главная страница (т.е. вид main.php), в котором и вывожу массив.

Comment: да, спасибо, там дей-но Controller_Base наследует класс Controller_Template. Получилось, а точнее дошло до меня!

Comment: @Viczech, я преобразовал комментарий в ответ. Если всё заработало, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с ответом).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$this->template->..` используется если `Controller_Base` реализует что-то похожее на `Controller_Template`. В таком случае он сам подгрузит main.php.
И тогда присваивать надо так:

```
$this->template->apps = $apps;
```

Ну или `bind`, если он вам больше нравится.